# C# Crystal report Insert->special field -> record number

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm using crystal report in my project i use serial number in my rows using Insert->special field -> record number

[image]

it shows perfect count of rows

[image]

but I'm getting an problem if crystal report is null. It shows 1

[image]

this is an problem . please help me how i did not get this 1 in my report.

Any ideas
thanks in advice Please Someone help me

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for your problem but easiest and simplest is probably that you go on your detail section and put suppresion formula if there is no records.

So to do that

- go to section expert
- write formula on detail section suppress trigger (picture)
  [image]
- formula should be like `if count({any_field_name} = 0)then true else false`

That should do it, hope it helps